# send data to running async function xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Working with Xamarin Android and C# -

I want to have a download function, that just download the next item (url) from the list if the first with index 0 is finished. While Downloading, the user should be able to extend the list (add new urls for download).

My idea was to have one `void OnButtonClick()` (for user input) and one custom `aysnc void Download()` function, as well the possibility to use the "share function" (intent) to send the link directly. It is working BUT only if the user does not uses the "share function" in another app (see here: Intent.GetStringExtra). If the App gets open via this intent, the download loop gets overwritten completely. Is there a way to avoid this "bug" or another solution for a download que?

```
protected override void OnCreate() //gets called if activity starts
{
   string catchedLink = Intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(catchedLink))
   {
         button.Text = catchedLink;
   }
}
public OnButtonClick()
{
   urlList.Add(Button.Text);
}

private aysnc void Download()
{
   if(IsDownloading) return;

   IsDownloading = true;
   do
   {
    await DownloadSomethingFromTheInternet(); //Let's say these two function need 2 mins to complete -
    await SafeItToStorage();                  //But after one minute the user adds a secound url for download
                                              //so this loop needs to run again (see below)

    urlList.Remove(urlList[0]);

   } while (urlList.Count >= 1)               //see here
   IsDownloading = false;
}
```

Please leave a comment if more details are needed.

Comment: What do you mean " the download loop gets overwritten completely" ?

Comment: I tested it now again more detailed: the problem is not that the "list gets overwritten" (reseted) but the whole activity starts again. it gets closed and starts again with the intent. While it starts again, the ```Download()``` function (called from the previous activity) stops. How to avoid that or is there a way for calling a task/function that runs in the background?

Comment: You mean the activity recreate ? Have you try to set the activity `LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask`，and receive the intent in the `OnNewIntent` method

Comment: I tried it and it's working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it's working now:

**What I did:**

- Save the links on the device with `Preferences.Set();` not only just with a List
- Added `LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask` to `AndroidMainfest.xml` (in `<activity [...] />`)
- Used for intent-input following code:

````
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent myIntent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(myIntent);
            string catchedLink = myIntent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraText);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(catchedLink))
            {
                AddVideoToQue(catchedLink);
            }
        }```

Thanks @Leo Zhu - MSFT for his comments and help!
````